# Segmentation fail? Why?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fault

I would convert a Binary-File with one or more Pascal-Strings into a .Txt file. This is the right way, but it appear a Segmentation fault. I don't understand, where's the problem. The file size is 23.

```
void printFile(char *buffer, char *output_file, int file_size)
{
  FILE *out_file = fopen(output_file, "w");
  int i = 0;
  int j = 1;
  int cnt = 0;
  int cnt_word = 0;
  int block = 4;

  while (i < block)
  {
    cnt = cnt + buffer[i];
    i++;
  }

  while (j <= cnt)
  {
    while (i < file_size)
    {
      while (i < (i + block))
      {
        cnt_word = cnt_word + buffer[i];
        i++;
      }

      while (i < (i + cnt_word))
      {
        fprintf(out_file, "%c", buffer[i]);
        i++;
      }

      fprintf(out_file, " ");
      cnt_word = 0;
      j++;
    }
  }

  fclose(out_file);
}
```

This is the in other Function `get filesize`:

```
fseek(in_file, 0, SEEK_END);
file_size = ftell(in_file);
rewind(in_file);

//allocate memory for buffer
buffer = malloc(file_size);
```

Comment: You don't show the calling function, so we don't know the size of "buffer".  You are most likely exceeding the array size.  Run it in a debugger.

Comment: How big is buffer? Also with so many while loops, I can only imagine one of them runs infinitely causing a stack overflow.

Comment: while (i < (i+block)) can this condition fail?

Comment: @sukunrt good catch. I was just saying one of these while loops are very likely to cause stack overflow, if it ever runs infinitely

Comment: If param file_size less than 4 there is infinite loop! "while ( i < file_size)" will always be false ! So variable j is not updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (i < (i + block))
```

Here block is 4, I don't see how this condition can fail

Comment: I'd say it fails for `i > (INT_MAX-block)`.

Comment: Since, he's accessing the array in the loop, I'd say it will segfault before it.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC pascal strings are stored with the length as first byte iow they are not stored with a terminating \0 as C-strings are

In order for you to show the string you need to check with a hex editor the exact format that is in the file.

You can however start by just setting your buffer to \0 using calloc and then putting the text in there so that is assured that the buffer is \0-terminated.